# error: SequelizeValidationError: string violation: created cannot be an array or an object

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am implementing MERN Stack Login / Registration and trying to test my response in Postman step by step. Firstly, I written the code for Registration then for Login but in case of calling registration link I am getting the following error in postman:

`error: SequelizeValidationError: string violation: created cannot be an array or an object`

Can someone provide any suggestions to help? I think in `User.js findone()` function is having some sort of miss from my side.

Could there be any other solution?

./database/DB.js

```
const db = {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize("mern", "root", "", {
        host: "localhost",
        dialect: "mysql",
        port: "3307",
        operatorsAliases: false,

        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.sequelize = sequelize

module.exports = db
```

./models/User.js

```
const db = require("../database/db")

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        id: {
             type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
             primaryKey: true,
             autoIncrement: true
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        created: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
);
```

./routes/User.js

```
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = require("../models/User")
users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date()
    const userData = {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        created: today
    }

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
         }
    })
        .then(user => {
            if(!user){
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    userData.password = hash
                    User.create(userData)
                        .then(user => {
                            res.json({status: user.email + ' registered'})
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            res.send('error: ' + err)
                        })
                })  
            }   else {
                res.json({error: "User already exists"})
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
})

users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(user) {
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                    expiresin: 1440
                })
                res.send(token)
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({error: 'User does not exist'})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err})
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

package.json

```
  "name": "login-registration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.2",
    "mysql": "^2.14.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "sequelize": "^4.38.0"
  }
}
```

Server.js

```
var cors = require ('cors')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var Users = require('./routes/users')

app.use('/users', Users)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running at port: " + port)
})
```

Comment: did you see an error , it's itself explain that your created property contains the different type of data, it should be a string not an object

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I can understand but I dont know where it is pointing in the code. Can you please specify?

Comment: change the data type of  created property string to date or use the value like today.toLocaleDateString()

Comment: It resolved that error. But now I am having {
    "status": "undefined registered"
}

Comment: It is resolved now. The second error occur due to wrong input. Now, its working like a cream. Thanks a alot Dhaval :).

Answer (score 3):

In ./routes/User.js, under the /post register route, the userData object has a created field with today property which is a Date object.

In ./models/User.js you specify that created should have type Sequelize.STRING.

This is the contradiction that is causing the error. When you call User.create(userData), it gives you that error because the input parameter is of the wrong type.

To fix this, you either need to have created expect a type of Sequlize.Date or convert the today date object to a string.

```
const today =  new Date().toJSON();
```

There are many different to string functions for the Date class. You should pick the one that best suits you [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 3):

> This error is as a result of submitting a value of a wrong type compared to the
> one declared in the model. Therefore, change it to the appropriate
> type which is "JSON" instead of "STRING".
>
> ./models/User.js

```
const db = require("../database/db")

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        id: {
             type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
             primaryKey: true,
             autoIncrement: true
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        created: {
            type: Sequelize.JSON
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the "today" attribute that's causing the issue, you are trying to save a date obj instead of string. Change it to string while saving.